# average of only diagonals of 2 a dimensional array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, diagonal

I have a C# midterm review question that is getting the best of me. The question is: "Use a method, and on the click of a button, call the method to sort through a 2 dimensional array (globally declared) and return the average of the first diagonal using a SINGLE for loop."

My 2 dimensional array looks like this

`int[,] A = new int[,] { { -16, 19, 8, -3 }, 
                                {-17, -5, 9, 33 },
                                {-2, 15, -13, 29 }, 
                                {25, 39, -23, 8 } };`

And my code thus far looks like this:

`private void btnAverageQVI_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            arrayAverage(A);

        }`

```
    `public static void arrayAverage(int[,] array)
    {
        int total = 0;
        int count = 0;

        int rows = array.GetLength(0);
        int cols = array.GetLength(1);

        for (rows = 0; rows < array.Length; rows++)
        {
            total = array[0, 0] + 1;
            count++;
        }
        double average = total / 4;
        MessageBox.Show("Total: " + average);
    }`
```

Someone please help, I feel like it's easy, but I am missing something.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void arrayAverage(int[,] array)
    {
        int total = 0;
        //Get number of rows 
        int rows = Math.Min(array.GetLength(0),array.GetLength(1));

        //Iterate through diagonal elements
        for (int i= 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            total += array[i, i];
        }
        //Multiple 1.0 to prevent data lost.
        double average = 1.0*total / rows;
        Console.WriteLine("Total: " + average);
    }
```